# Dynamically added control (DataGridView) doesn't work properly

Tags: vb.net

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017788/code-to-show-a-datagridview-works-only-if-i-run-another-sub-before) and, after many attempts, I accepted the answer who suggested me to use an hidden control instead of an added control.

This way my code run correctly but I would like to understand the mistake.

That's what happens:
When I press a button a new DataGridView is added but
a) it isn't visible even if his property visible is set True;
b) if (while the added DGV is on the form) I set DGV property visible to False and then I re-set it to True the DGV appears but columns aren't resized;
c) if I remove the added DGV and re-add it, it is "invisible" again.

ALL THESE TROUBLES DON'T HAPPEN IF I RUN ANOTHER SUB

If:
a) I run a sub that hides my first form and shows another form;
b) then I close the 2nd form to go back to the first form;
all works fine:
the DGV is correctly added;
it is visible;
all columns are correctly resized;
if I remove the DGV or re-add it, all still works.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Whats your code for adding the DGV?

Comment: @Aimnox All the code is in my other question. I gave the link at the start of this question.

Comment: Try adding 

'Me.Hide() 
Me.Show()'

in 1st form after you create the datagridview to see if it's really because of the hide/unhide process of form 1 ?

Comment: @HaPhan YES! I tryed as you suggested (a button with `Me.Hide() Me.Show()` ) and the code worked. So I tryed to modify `MyBase.Load` (without luck). Please suggest me where to look for the bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I got from your earlier link. It shows the datagridview as expected in my form. As you can see, it is exactly your code, with the exception of that "using" block --- and the way you retrieve the datatable. That's the only two differences.

```
Private Sub ShowHideTbl()
    Dim DTemp As DataTable = GetTable()
    Dim DGV_Tbl As DataGridView = Nothing
    Try
        DGV_Tbl = CType(Me.Controls("DGV_Tbl"), DataGridView)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    If DGV_Tbl Is Nothing Then
        If Me.CBox_ProcType.Text = "Select a Procedure" Then
            MsgBox("You need To select a Procedure", vbInformation, "Unable to show table")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    DGV_Tbl = New DataGridView
    With DGV_Tbl
        .Name = "DGV_Tbl"
        .DataSource = DTemp
        Me.Controls.Add(DGV_Tbl)
        .AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)
        .RowHeadersVisible = False
        .AllowUserToAddRows = False
        .AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    End With
    Dim DGV_H As Integer = 0
    Dim DGV_W As Integer = 0
    For Each S As DataGridViewRow In DGV_Tbl.Rows
        DGV_H += S.Height
    Next
    DGV_H += DGV_Tbl.ColumnHeadersHeight
    'Add more space to include spaces between cells
    DGV_H += CInt(DGV_Tbl.Rows.Count * 0.45)
    For Each S As DataGridViewColumn In DGV_Tbl.Columns
        DGV_W += S.Width
    Next
    'Add more space to include spaces between cells
    DGV_W += CInt(DGV_Tbl.Columns.Count * 0.45)
    DGV_Tbl.Height = DGV_H
    DGV_Tbl.Width = DGV_W
    'Resize the Form
    Me.Height += DGV_H + 30
    Me.Controls("DGV_Tbl").Location = New Point(15, Me.Height - DGV_H - 30)
End Sub
```

Your problem is most strange, and since I don't have the code to try and test, my only suggest is that you paste this code into a new form, see if it works. If it does, then add your other control of form 1 into it, run the code again, see if it still work. Repeat the process until you find out what is the cause.

I believe you can find out what is really happening in your form with this. Who know, that new form will probably work.